# Identify two users with the same email address

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently working on a parental control application, what I would want to achieve is that the parent and child can login to the system with the same email address on different devices, and I also want to achieve auto login feature, when the parent open the app, it will directly load the ParentActivity, if child then load the ChildActivity.

But now the problem is that I can't do this, I have no idea how to identify both of them since they are using the same email address. Previously, I was able to perform auto login for the parent by using FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(), and then check the userType inside firestore. But now I can't check anything to identify whether the user is a child or parent.

What I have tried:

1. Create a field call "child", when the user (John) login as child, update the field with "TRUE" (let's say), when John quit app and login again, the system will starting checking if userType == "parents", if no then only it will check if child == "TRUE". Therefore, the child user will always be auto login to the ParentActivity but ChildActivity.

Is there any way to achieve this? Hope you guys understand what my problem is. The attached image shows how I achieve auto login for parent previously. Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Transparent Status Bar
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    //FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this.getBaseContext());
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    clearUserType();
}

// Hide keyboard after user clicking somewhere
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
            INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    return true;
}

@OnClick(R.id.LoginButton)
public void login(){
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (!Utils.isValidEmail(email, emailLayout) | !Utils.hasEmail(email, emailLayout) | !Utils.hasPassword(password, passwordLayout)){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return;
    }
    startSignIn(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
}

@OnClick(R.id.SignUpButton)
public void signUpScreen(){
    Intent signup = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
    startActivity(signup);
    finish();
}

@OnTextChanged(value = R.id.LoginEmailText, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
public void emailChanged(CharSequence s){
    if(!(s.length() < 1)){
        emailLayout.setError(null);
    }
}

@OnTextChanged(value = R.id.LoginPasswordText, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
public void passwordChanged(CharSequence s){
    if(!(s.length() < 1)){
        passwordLayout.setError(null);
    }
}

private void startSignIn(String email, String password){
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                try {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        updateUI();
                    }
                    else {
                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                        if (error.contains("There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.") ||
                            error.contains("The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."))
                        {
                            Utils.ErrorSweetDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed", "Incorrect email or pasword. Please try again.",
                                    "OK");
                        }
                        else if (error.contains("A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.")){
                            Utils.ErrorSweetDialog(LoginActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                                    "Please check your internet connection and try again.", "OK");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Utils.ErrorSweetDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed", error, "OK");
                        }
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Utils.ErrorSweetDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Oops! Something went wrong.",
                            "Sorry for the inconvenience. Please try again later.", "OK");
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //clearUserType();
    //FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    /*DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("UserInfo").document(uid); //ZJkUy7J5UzTok7ioADAYqk77Opp1
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if(document.exists()){
                    String userType = document.getString("userType");
                    Log.e("LoginActivity",userType);
                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });*/

    /*if(user != null){
        //updateUI();
        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("UserInfo").document(uid); //ZJkUy7J5UzTok7ioADAYqk77Opp1
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if(document.exists()){
                        String userType = document.getString("userType");
                        Log.e("LoginActivity",userType);
                        if (userType.contains("parents")){
                            Log.e("contain parents", "yes");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Log.e("Login", "hi");
    }*/
}

private void updateUI(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PickRoleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

private void clearUserType(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    //Log.e("urrent user", user.toString());
    if(user != null){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.e("user null: ", "no");
        //updateUI();
        String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Log.e("UID: ",uid);
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("UserInfo").document(uid); //ZJkUy7J5UzTok7ioADAYqk77Opp1
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if(document.exists()){
                        String userType = document.getString("userType");
                        String childStatus = document.getString("child");
                        Log.e("LoginActivity",userType);
                        if (userType.contains("parents")){
                            Log.e("contain parents", "yes");
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else if (childStatus.contains("TRUE")){
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("task unsuccessful:", " yes");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Log.e("NULL: ", "No Such User.");
    }
}
```

}

[User account data in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2gpw.png)

Comment: when the user logout, did you remove the value `userType`?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes, I did

Comment: so, when the user login check again, everytime user login, check again

Comment: ya, everytime will check if userType is equal to "parents", if yes only auto login, else load login page. This is for parent auto login. But child I have no idea how to do it

Comment: can you post your codes instead screenshot.

Comment: you mean the whole zip file right?

Comment: no. change your images there to codes, share them here

Comment: How do you differentiate a child from parent?

Comment: @Ticherhaz updated, if you need any other activity code, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @AlexMamo I assume that you are saying how can I identify the child and the parent, since they are using the same email password to login and this is the problem. Previously, for parent, I check the firestore userType, and I didn't notice the issue until I work on the child side. So I'm finding a way to differentiate them, so that the system won't load activity wrongly.

Comment: I still don't understand how you differentiate them? Since the child uses the same email can also access the parent's account, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are enabling creation of multiple accounts with the same email address, which means the parent and the child have different passwords. With that, I suggest you take a look at [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?authuser=1#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk). It basically give an account a 'tag' that you can access client side. Please notice that this will require you to write some Cloud Functions when creating accounts

EDIT: It's seem that you need a SharedPreferences. Here are the docs : developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences . This way you can store a key like `isParent:true` in a SharedPreferences, and read its value everytime the app is started instead of saving it to Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm not enabling that feature. The child doesn't have to create an account. He/she will just simply use the parent email password to sign in. Then  the system will ask who's using this device, parent or child. if parent clicked, goes to ParentActivity, child goes to ChildActivity.

Comment: @SYL then how about a local-only variable? Because you only need it to show 1 of the 2 UIs, I don't think that need to go to Firestore. Just keep a local variable, no?

Comment: But how that can achieve auto login? Cuz now what I'm doing is in onCreate method of LoginActivity, I check if the user data is inside the cache by using FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(), if yes then it will straight away load the main activity instead of the login activity. How to do that by using just a local variable? I will appreciate it, if you could elaborate more. Thanks

Comment: You can save it to a SharedPreferences. Here are the docs : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences .

Comment: this way, when you reopen the app you can still tell which UIs to go to

Comment: After reading the documentation of SharedPreferences,  I still don’t understand how can it solves the problem. For my understanding, it is like a mini notepad or something right? Similar to firestore. How that can identify both of them?

Comment: you can save like `isParent:true` and check the `isParent` key everytime you start your app. The benefit of using SharedPreferences is they are offline and simpler so you don't need to worry about Firestore

Comment: I think I get what you mean (maybe), this is really a good way to store small data, will consider it. However, that's not my question. I will give an example, let's say device A login using a@a.com and choose to login as parent, then the userType value stored in firestore will be "parents". Then no problem for this device to perform auto login as the system will check if userType=="parents", load ParentActivity.

Comment: The problem is when another device B also login to the system using same email password and login as child. Then if I use the same way and change the userType to "child". Now when device A open the app again, the system will load the ChildActivity instead of ParentActivity. Therefore, is there anyway to uniquely identify both of them such as maybe store the phone number of the user as well as the userType, so everytime user login, the system will check these two values and direct users to different UIs. Hope this example can give you an idea of my problem and also thank you for your patient.

Comment: that's exactly why I suggest you to use SharedPreferences. Device A and device B won't share `isParent` key. I'm not saying to stop using Firestore, just store the `isParent` key or any name in a SharedPreferences and store everything that can be shared between parent and child on Firestore. That way device A will only get its key and device B will also only get its key

Comment: OMG!! I finally did it, it worked! I was struggling for this logical problem for about 1 to 2 days, didn't expect that the solution to be so simple. Once again thank you for your patient and also thanks for introducing me a new term. Really **APPRECIATE** it!

Comment: Also, you may need to update your answer. I'm very happy to accept it as the best answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can check them at `onCreate` for Login Activity or if you have Splash Activity, you can check there.

```
   DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("UserInfo").document(uid); //ZJkUy7J5UzTok7ioADAYqk77Opp1
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if(document.exists()){
                    String userType = document.getString("userType");
                    Log.e("LoginActivity",userType);
                    if (userType.equal("parents")){
                        Log.e("contain parents", "yes");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else if (userType.equal("child")) {
                        //Here you missed, when child login
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think maybe there is some misunderstanding. For now I'm doing this way to check the parent, but the userType of an email can be parents or child, If let's say device A login using a@a.com and choose to login as parent, then the userType value will be "parents". Then there will be no problem for this device to perform auto login. But if another device B also login to the system using same email password and login as child. Then the userType will change to "child". Now when device A open the app, the system will load the ChildActivity instead of Parent. I hope you get what I mean ya xD

Comment: I see, as ThienLD commented, you can save it to a SharedPreferences.